# NUnit UITest run in sequence of one another

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, nunit, xamarin.uitest

***Question:***

I have a Xamarin.UITest project setup with NUnit framework. I know that using [Test, Setup] provides me the ability to have a setup test that is ran before each test. I was wondering if there is a way to have my [Test, Setup] run before each test, but then have the tests that follow pickup on the exact page where the setup left off?

***Why:***

I have about 6 or 7 UITests that test a specific page within our application. I am trying to minimize redundancy, so any automation that navigates me to that page (I believe) should be done once in a separate method; *i.e: the setup method*.

I have searched S.O. as well as NUnit.org, I just don't know how to do *my specific ask*. Please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: [`SetUp`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUp-and-TearDown) will run per-test

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Right. 1. (Setup -> Test), 2. (Setup -> Test), 3. (Setup -> Test)....

Each time a Test starts, it does NOT start from where the Setup left off. How can I accomplish that

Comment: Have a look at [`TestContext`](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/TestContext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apoligies for a 2nd answer, but it appears you want to do:

```
public class MyTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test1()
    {
        Setup1();
        DoSomeTests();
    }

     [Test]
    public void Test2()
    {
        Setup1();
        Setup2();

        DoSomeTests();

    }

    private void Setup1()
    {
    }
    private void Setup2()
    {

    }


 }
```

Comment: Neil, that makes perfect sense. Actually, that's very similar to what I had initially done while trying things out - I just wasn't sure if there was a "better" way to do it. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OneTimeSetup] to run before ALL tests in a class.
You can use [Setup] to run be EACH test in a class.
You can use [TearDown] to run after EACH test in a class.

```
[TestFixture]
public class Mytests
{
   [OneTimeSetup] 
   public void ThisWillRunBeforeAllTests()
   { }

   [Setup]
   public void ThisWillRunBeforeEachTest()
   { }

   [TearDown]
   public void ThisWillRunAfterEachTest()
   { }

   [Test]
   public void ATest()
   { }
```

Comment: Right... (OneTimeSetup (1. (Setup -> Test -> TearDown), 2. (Setup -> Test -> TearDown), 3. (Setup -> Test -> TearDown))).... Each time a Test starts, it does NOT start from where the Setup left off. How can I accomplish that

Comment: You can't. That's not how unit tests work.  If you want that kind of functionality, just have one [test] and call each sub-'test' from that.   If any part of the test fails, the whole thing fails, but that's probably what you want anyway, as a subsequent part may require one of the previous (failing) tests so succeed, so it wont' work anyway.